# Encode Ampersand in JSON output in ASP.NET Core WebAPI End Point

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am looking for a way to encode all amersands in JSON returned from an end point in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API project.  I want to encode all amersands as "\u0026".  Currently my JSON is showing "&" in the output like this.

```
{"status":"3 & 1",...
```

But I want it to appear like this.

```
{"status":"3 \u0026 1",...
```

Is there an option for this?

My current JsonOptions options are....

```
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml));
```

I am letting .NET handle the JSON serialization and I am not specifically encoding the output.  My end point looks like this.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<StatSheet> Index()
{
   var statSheet = new StatSheet();
   ... <processing to fill the entity here>
   return statSheet
}
```

Comment: Does [`StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm) not work?  It seems as though it should.  In fact, it does seem to work the way you want in a standalone console app: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAXsQe.  What are you seeing instead?

Comment: I thought so too but it is not.  Description says HTML (<, >, &, ', ") and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.

Comment: The fiddle is not how am I returning JSON.  I updated the answer to indicate I am not using SerializeObject.

Comment: That's interesting.  What about other options?  Is `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` being respected correctly?  What if you modify some other setting with an obvious impact, e.g by setting `options.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() },` -- does that work?

Comment: Well, either that specific option is being ignored, or somehow all options are being ignored -- but I can't see from the [reference source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonOutputFormatter.cs) where that might be happening.  Can you try adding `EscapingStringConverter` from https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOqmcs to `options.Converters` to see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: NullVauleHandling.Ignore and SnakeCaseNamingStrategy work.  Strange that StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml is not working.

Comment: Strange indeed.  What about `EscapingStringConverter` from the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOqmcs?

Comment: I realized what's happening.  I just started using FireFox and it's default representation of JSON pretties up the display including translating escape characters.  Looking at the Raw Data view in FireFox shows it correctly.  EscapingStringConverter from your fiddle and StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml both work fine.  Aggghh!  Sorry for wasting your time but I really appreciate the help!!!